# Screen flickering and tearing

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 19.10, flicker, tearing

I am currently on Ubuntu 19.10 and I am having trouble with the screen flickering sporadically, sometimes several times per minute sometimes less. There is also small horizontal screen tear when I scroll or similar.

I have a Nvidia 130M graphics unit, and I have activated the proprietary drivers:

[image]

I'd have thought any graphics issues would be resolved by using the correct drivers, but since the problem persists, I was hoping someone could help me find a solution. Checking checking graphics units and drivers in terminal yields:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
```

and

```
$ sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] passord for *user*: 

 *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:139 memory:ed000000-edffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM108M [GeForce MX130]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:142 memory:ee000000-eeffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:ef000000-ef07ffff
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Screen Tearing in Linux with Nvidia Graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185277/screen-tearing-in-linux-with-nvidia-graphics/1185328#1185328)?