# Screen Tearing on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: graphics, 20.04, screen

I started using Ubuntu 20.04 two days ago, and this has been a nonstop issue. There would be constant screen tearing.

Now, I did come to this forum and tried the many solutions. Such as these two:

[Screen tearing in Ubuntu with Nvidia/Intel graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667466/screen-tearing-in-ubuntu-with-nvidia-intel-graphics)

[Screen Tearing on Ubuntu Xorg 20.04 with Intel Graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234026/screen-tearing-on-ubuntu-xorg-20-04-with-intel-graphics)

However, none of them work. If anyone can help me out with this issue, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you.

Also, I'm still very new to Ubuntu, so please bear with me.

UPDATE: I did try the dri3 method. While it seems to work, the screen and mouse cursor needs to be absolutely still. I've given up at this point for now, but if anyone is still willing to help, I'd really appreciate it.

These are my specs:

- CPU: Quad Core Intel Core i5-8265U (-MT MCP-) speed/min/max:
  600/400/3900 MHz
- Kernel: 5.4.0-33-generic x86_64 Up: 9m Mem: 1877.9/15899.4 MiB(11.8%)
- Storage: 931.51 GiB (7.5% used) Procs: 278 Shell: bash 5.0.16 inxi:
  3.0.38

  ```
     display                 
     description: VGA compatible controller
     product: UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 2
     bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
     version: 02
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
     configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
     resources: irq:128 memory:a0000000-a0ffffff memory:80000000-9fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  ```

Comment: I guess you aren't using a discrete graphic card.Did you try adding `nomodeset` to the line in grub file `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Comment: How do I do that? I haven't tried that. I'm just getting into Ubuntu, so please bear with me.

Comment: edit the grub file by `sudo vim /etc/default/grub` In there you can see the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE` just add `nomodeset` at the last. Hope It helps

Comment: Tried it. All it gave me was [sudo: vim: command not found]

Comment: vim is not installed in your system try instead with  `sudo gedit ..` after that do `sudo update-grub` and reboot the system

Comment: I did that, and it currently shows me the text editor when I typed sudo gedit.. I apologize if I'm being a bit redundant, still learning.

Comment: My bad, I should elaborate more. Here's what you need to do

`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` after that make the changes, and save by `ctrl+s` and close it. after that do `sudo update-grub`

Comment: I'm there now. Thanks. I see 11GRUB_CMDLINE_LINIX" ". I see a blank spot at twelve as well. Do I type it next to the line of text or do I type it in the blank 12 spot?

Comment: just add to the same line. It will be like `quiet splash`, change it to `quiet splash nomodeset`

Comment: Alright. Did that. But when I did, I got this warning in the terminal.

(gedit:4326): Tepl-WARNING **: 13:43:15.050: GVfs metadata is not supported. Fallback to TeplMetadataManager. Either GVfs is not correctly installed or GVfs metadata are not supported on this platform. In the latter case, you should configure Tepl with --disable-gvfs-metadata.

Comment: Nevermind that. After saving do the update `sudo update-grub` then `sudo reboot`

Comment: Okay. I did the sudo update-grub command, and it read back Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 10: /etc/default/grub: nomodeset: not found

Comment: Can you copy and paste the line you edited, as a comment

Comment: Here it is: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" nomodeset

Comment: `nomodeset` should be in the quotes. `"quiet splash nomodeset"`

Comment: Okay. Now it works. Gonna reboot and see if this worked.

Comment: If It doesn't work check this https://learnubuntumate.weebly.com/screen-tearing-on-intel-graphics.html

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, and I can no longer control the brightness, and it won't display on my TV either. I'll undo the settings to see if that'll fix it. Thank you so much for helping me out though. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to upvote

Comment: In the links you tried you may need to add other few extra option like `Option  "AccelMethod" "uxa"` or `Option  "TripleBuffer" "true"` in the `20-intel.conf` file. As per: https://www.pcsuggest.com/fix-linux-screen-tearing/

Comment: Did you try this: [Screen Tearing in Linux with Nvidia Graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185277/screen-tearing-in-linux-with-nvidia-graphics/1185328#1185328)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with Intel UHD 620 on Thinkpad T490. 
I don't know why but changing from Xorg to Wayland resolve the problem.
However videos played with VLC/Chrome browser don't have this issue.

To fix the problem with Firefox you need to type in the URL `about:config`.
After "Accepting the risk", type in the search bar `layers.acceleration.force-enabled` and set it on `true`.

I personally don't like this solution because it seems to be a system problem with Xorg. I checked on Xubuntu 20.04 and Kubuntu 20.04 and both don't have tearing at all.

Hoping to find a real solution soon.