# saving a X config file for nvidia setting disables my PRIME internal display

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, multiple-monitors, xorg, display

I'm on ubuntu 20.04. I'm using an external monitor with a laptop as shown in nvidia-settings here:
[image]

nominally this works. But, to get rid of tearing on the external display, I need to select "Force Composition Pipeline" under Advanced. This is fine, but when I try to save the X config file, a restart would remove my PRIME display completely. Only my external monitor works.

I would have to delete /etc/X11/xorg.conf to get the display back.

Is there a way to save this config and keep the prime display?

Comment: I am having the same issue...after saving to X config file, even if I select "merge" the internal screen isn't working.
nomodset only fixes the issue for internal screen.

Comment: @adi - Did you have a chance of testing what I proposed?

Answer (score 2):

You may try [this solution](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-save-the-x-server-settings/128896/2), which seems to have worked for others.

1. Remove any `xorg.conf` in `/etc/X11`
2. Create directory `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`
3. Create file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia-antitear.conf` with contents

   ```
    Section "OutputClass"
        Identifier "nvidia-antitear"
        MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
        Driver "nvidia"
        Option "ForceCompositionPipeline" "true"
    EndSection
   ```

Related: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA/Troubleshooting#Avoid_screen_tearing

---

Alternatively, you could write a script that applies the settings as mentioned by adi, but run it at boot time via `crontab` so it works for any user.
This is done [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1185328/226614).

The solution via [compton](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/compton.1.html) posted there is yet another option.

Comment: Seems to work, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I've found a solution, courtesy of answer from the following question: [How to automatically force full composition pipeline for Nvidia GPU driver?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510757/how-to-automatically-force-full-composition-pipeline-for-nvidia-gpu-driver)

I've changed the solution a bit though.

Step 1, create a shell script file, wherever you want, I've made it like in the answer in `~/bin/force-composition-pipeline.sh`

Step 2, add the following content to the scrip:

```
#!/bin/bash
s="$(nvidia-settings -q CurrentMetaMode -t)"

if [[ "${s}" != "" ]]; then
  s="${s#*" :: "}"
  nvidia-settings -a CurrentMetaMode="${s//\}/, ForceCompositionPipeline=On\}}"
fi
```

Step 3, make the script executable:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/force-composition-pipeline.sh
```

Step 4, add the script to the sign in process, either by adding the following code to the `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, whichever you find in your home directory:

```
if [ -f "$HOME/bin/force-composition-pipeline.sh" ] ; then
    ~/bin/force-composition-pipeline.sh
fi
```

Comment: This solution was the only one that worked for me with Ubuntu 22. You can put he script directly in the profile, no need to create another file.